# How to consume external REST API on Abp Framework's Application layer?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, abp

I'm using tiered ABP Framework version 7.
I want to call external *REST API* service from let's say `localhos:6767` url.

External application also uses the swagger so I know exactly how the data should be structured.

**Q:** What's the best practice to call and consume REST API only for the **Application layer**, without adding additional nugget package to my project?

Note that I've already checked the [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Static-CSharp-API-Clients) . However, it's not easy to follow. If possible, please provide a simple example.